# How to get more info from npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using `npm install` on Windows, and want to get more information about this:

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
```

Earlier versions of `npm` dumped the installation progress into the console, but the current version (3.3.12) just displays a progress bar.  The above warnings appear, but I have no idea what package they're referring to.

How can I get `npm` to behave as it used to and dump its output to the console?  Or, how can I write a logfile of `npm install`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get npm to output more details you can try using `npm install --verbose` or if that isn't enough you could try `npm install --loglevel silly`

Comment: Thanks.  `--verbose` did the trick.  The package giving the warning was "fsevents".  I guess it's not supported on Windows.  I'm unsure why the warning appears twice, but I think that's the only troublesome package.

Answer (score 2):

This command is to store the npm install error log in a file

`npm install --loglevel verbose > log.txt 2>&1`

you will find `log.txt` in your root directory of the project